# C++: How to implement private helper function that requires access to protected members of a class without altering header file?

Tags: c++, function, helper

I'm trying to declare and use a generic helper function to do recursion.
The issue is, I **cannot touch the default header file**.
We are allowed to linked the default header file and add implementation to another header file, however, I don't know how to add more functions to the class Node declared in the default without the redefinition error.
**Note**: there are getters for the Node class but no setters, same for Tree.
**Note2**: We can only linked the default header file, cannot add other headers files.

What I want if I can declare the helper:

```
template <class T>
void Tree<T>::add(const T &x){
    if(root){
        root->insertNode(x);
    } else{
        root = new Node<T>(x);
    }
}

template <class T>
void Node::insertNode(T const &x){
    if(x < value){
        if(left){
            left->insertNode(x);
        } else{
            left = new Node<T>(x);
        }
    } else if(x > value){
        if(right){
            right->insertNode(x);
        } else{
            right = new Node<T>(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Which leads to this error:

```
Out-of-line definition of 'insertNode' does not match any declaration in 'Node<T>'
```

Because the helper function wasn't defined in the default header.
I can't declare Node::insertNode without changing the default header.

As you can see, the helper **needs access to protected members of Node** (data, left, right).
I tried passing (Node*) as additional parameter to the helper as a free function, but then I don't know how to set left and right with just getters (there are no setter functions in the header).
So I can't set it to a free function without declaring it as friend in the header, which again, I can't touch.

What can I do? Suggestion?

---

Edit:
Following suggestion of @darune, I tried passing in reference as param:

```
template <class Base>
void insertNode(const Base &item, Node<T>& node){
    if(item < node->data){
        if(node->left){
            insertNode(item, node->left);
        } else{
            node->left = new BSTNode<Base>(item);
        }
    } else if(node->data > item){
        if(node->right){
            insertNode(item, node->right);
        } else{
            node->right = new BSTNode<Base>(item);
        }
    }
}
```

But then I get:

```
error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'Node<int>'
if(item < node->data)
```

If I try to change the -> to . (like node.data), then it just says:

```
Node<T>::data is protected within this context
```

---

Edit2:
Using template argument as reference param (not sure if correct):

```
template <class T, class S>
void insertNode(const Base &item, S& node){
    if(item < node->data){
        if(node->left){
            insertNode(item, node->left);
        } else{
            node->left = new BSTNode<Base>(item);
        }
    } else if(node->data > item){
        if(node->right){
            insertNode(item, node->right);
        } else{
            node->right = new BSTNode<Base>(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Gives me the same issue as above:

```
error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'Node<int>'
if(item < node->data)
```

Comment: In all reality, it would help if you added the sources which have been given to you (specifically, the header). Optimally, you would boil your problem down to an artificial class which does nothing and has a single protected data member, and explain exactly what it is you want to do. For example, are there inline definitions for the member functions present in the header (as they typically would be for a template)? If not, and you are actually trying to implement member functions, it's a totally different matter. (I'm asking because `BST<T>::insert`, which you change, is a member function.)

Comment: wiorz - please DO NOT add answers into the question - this makes question to no longer be a question thus deserving to be closed/deleted. You are welcome to post your solutions as answer (if they are different from existing answers) as long they are actually answering the question *as asked*. I rolled back your edit that invalidated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the language rules you cannot add a member helper function without modifying the header file.

What you could do:

- Either create standalone helper function (non-member) and work with the public interface of Node

or

- Create a wrapper, for ex. `class NodeWrapper : public Node` and work with the wrapper class:

  ```
   template <typename T>
    class NodeWrapper : public Node<T>
    {
         void insertNode(const T& x)
         {
          ... rest of the code ...
          ... you can access protected member of Node here, but not the private ones
         }
    }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, can you show me an example of how to define/use a wrapper class? I've never tried it before.

Comment: I tried doing it with a wrapper but feels that the solution is not what we are supposed to do since it requires converting the root to a wrapper, which requires a constructor for the wrapper? Otherwise I don't know how to call the wrapper from root.

Comment: If this is an assignment writing a derived class (wrapper, if you want) is certainly what's to be learned here.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica It's not an assignment on wrapper class. It's just using node and trees. We haven't even learn wrapper class yet.

Comment: @wiorz The assignment may not mention inheritance, but you have a class containing protected members. The meaning od `protected` is "inaccessible from the outside except by derived classes". Logically, if the task is to use a protected member, it means you must use a derived class (wrapper, if you want).. Alternatively, you can simply `#define protected public` above the include for the header, but that's probably not what the teacher had in mind ;-).

Answer (score -1):

You could just pass a reference (or a pointer) to the protected/private member into the function that needs to work on it. That way you still uphold all language and design principles. Also an added benefit is improved encapsulation.

Something like:

```
void insertNode(const auto& x, auto& left, auto& right){
```

Also, try to avoid using *raw pointers* in c++ (unless you have a good reason to). It's the modern way. Passing a raw pointer to a function is the only place where it still makes sense, since means it is optional (and hence should be reflected inside the function).

Comment: @wiorz Ah, you are still passing as pointer - if you really want that then just use `auto* left` instead.

Comment: @wiorz try to avoid 'raw pointers' when doing c++ if you can - its the modern way of c++.

Comment: I cannot declare auto&. The IDE (CLion) yells at me saying: "auto' not allowed in function prototype"

Comment: @wiorz then just use template arguments instead - serves the same purpose.

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob, but how do I pass in template arguments as a param?

Comment: @wiorz template<class T, class U, class V> etc.

Comment: @wiorz also remember to upvote my post and accept it

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could `auto` declare parameters like that.

Comment: Okay, just tried that (can see my edit above), same error as "-> has non-pointer type...". Which if I change to node.data, then it has it's protected.

Comment: I'm also not sure how you can access the protected members whose addresses you want to pass in a freestanding function. They are protected for a reason (to maintain an invariant which is part of the class's contract).